# How do I idiomatically convert a bool to an Option or Result in Rust?

Tags: types, casting, rust, type-conversion

It seems there is no way of such one-line conversion using `std`.

I do not like this kind of verbosity:

```rust
match my_bool {
    true => Ok(()),
    false => Err(MyError::False),
}
```

I would like to use a one-liner, for example:

```rust
let my_bool = true;
let my_option = my_bool.to_option(MyObject{}); // true => MyObject{}, false => None
let my_result = my_bool.to_result(MyObject{}, MyError{}); // true => MyObject{}, false => MyError{}
```

What is the shortest piece of code for doing that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**This answer is somewhat outdated**. Starting with Rust 1.50, you can use the built-in `bool::then`. See the other answers above for more information.

---

There is the [`boolinator` crate](https://crates.io/crates/boolinator). It defines [the extension trait `Boolinator`](https://docs.rs/boolinator/*/boolinator/trait.Boolinator.html) for `bool` which adds a couple of useful methods. Example:

```
use boolinator::Boolinator;

my_bool.as_some(MyObject {});                // Option<MyObject>
my_bool.as_result(MyObject {}, MyError {});  // Result<MyObject, MyError>
```

A `true` value leads to `Some(_)` or `Ok(_)`, while a `false` value leads to `None` or `Err(_)`.

There is an [issue about adding functionality like this to `std`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2606) on the RFCs repository, but it doesn't look like it's happening anytime soon.

Answer (score 63):

As of Rust 1.50 you can use [`bool::then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then):

```rust
assert_eq!(false.then(|| val), None);
assert_eq!(true.then(|| val), Some(val));
```

You can convert it to a `Result` by chaining [`Option::ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or):

```rust
assert_eq!(false.then(|| val).ok_or(err), Err(err));
assert_eq!(true.then(|| val).ok_or(err), Ok(val));
```

As of Rust 1.62, you can use [`bool::then_some`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then_some) and pass a value directly instead of creating a closure:

```rust
assert_eq!(false.then_some(val), None);
assert_eq!(true.then_some(val), Some(val));
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Option::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter):

```rust
assert_eq!(Some(obj).filter(|_| false), None);
assert_eq!(Some(obj).filter(|_| true).ok_or(err), Ok(obj));
```

Answer (score 38):

[`bool.then_some()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then_some) does this:

```rust
let my_bool = true;
let my_option = my_bool.then_some(MyObject{});
let my_result = my_bool.then_some(MyObject{}).ok_or(MyError{});
```

At the time of writing, this is still part of the experimental [`bool_to_option`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64260) feature.

**Update**: As of Rust 1.62, this feature has been stabilized.

Answer (score 8):

Use an `if` expression:

```rust
if my_bool { Ok(()) } else { Err(MyError::False) }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the standard library functions. The [`then`](https://crates.io/crates/then) crate provides `some` and `some_with` methods on booleans.

```rust
use then::Some

// returns Some(value) if my_bool is true
my_bool.some(value); 

// returns Some(value_fn()) if my_bool is true
my_bool.some_with(value_fn);
```

**Disclaimer:** I wrote this crate because I find it annoying that `my_bool.some_with(value)` is longer than `my_bool.some(|| value)`. And using the `_with` suffix is more consistent with the Rust naming for lazily evaluated functions.