# Idiomatic way to just return Err() on expression evaluation to false

Tags: error-handling, rust, boolean-expression, early-return

All what I'm looking for is to have one-liner like:

```
assert!( 1 == 2 );
```

but instead of panic, want to just return `MyErr()`.

For now I implement this way:

```
(1==2).then(|| ()).ok_or(MyErr())?;
```

Is there a cleaner way to do the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I idiomatically convert a bool to an Option or Result in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841351/how-do-i-idiomatically-convert-a-bool-to-an-option-or-result-in-rust)

Comment: @Krish I don't think this is duplicate since I was specific enough that proposed solution is something like I'm using right now.

Comment: Just wandering, is there some standard macro for that purpose?  Don't want to reinvent the wheel by naming own macros.

Comment: Just use an if statement: `if !(1==2) { return Err(e) }`

Answer (score 1):

As @Krish mentioned, use an `if` statement here. For reference, this is also what [`bool.then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/bool.rs.html#31) *basically* does:

```
pub fn then<T, F: FnOnce() -> T>(self, f: F) -> Option<T> {
    if self { Some(f()) } else { None }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for now the best option is:

```rust
if !(1==2) { return Err() }
```